# How can i change wpf listview selected Item style same as selected item in windows 8 store application?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to change listview selected item style in wpf same as it shown in my Windows 8 store application, attached image can be use for reference.

[Image link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/178201)

purple border and tick mark at top right corner.

Comment: Not to derail you, but... why? :)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you will need to modify the actual control template of the ListView.

Comment: I already added purple border,but i am unable to add tick mark on top right corner on selected item.

Comment: Look for a glyph element on the control template.

Comment: `SelectingGlyph` and `HintGlyph`

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably use the `ListBox` control rather than the WPF's `ListView` since WPF's `ListBox` is closer to WinRT/XAML's `ListView`. Then you'd want to set `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` to something resembling WinRT/XAML's `ListViewItem` style, which you can see a version of here.

(below is a copy with trimmed formatting to make it fit in Stack Overflow's 30k character limit).

```
<!-- Style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem -->
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded">
 <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
 <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
 <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,18,2"/>
 <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
 <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
 <Setter Property="Template">
 <Setter.Value>
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
 <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
 <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
 <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
 <Storyboard>
 <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
 <Storyboard>
 <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 </VisualStateGroup>
 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
 <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
 <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
 </VisualStateGroup>
 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionHintStates">
 <VisualState x:Name="VerticalSelectionHint">
 <Storyboard>
 <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="15" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
 <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
 <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
 <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="15" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0:0:0.500">
 <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.5" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
 <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.500" />
 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="HorizontalSelectionHint">
 <Storyboard>
 <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToHorizontalOffset="-23" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
 <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToHorizontalOffset="-23" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
 <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToHorizontalOffset="-23" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
 <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToHorizontalOffset="-23" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0:0:0.500">
 <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.5" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
 <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.500" />
 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionHint" />
 <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
 <VisualTransition To="NoSelectionHint" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.65"/>
 </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
 </VisualStateGroup>
 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
 <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="0.5" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="Selecting">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 </VisualStateGroup>
 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
 <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />
 <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
 <Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDragContent"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
 <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="InnerDragContent" />
 <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" />
 <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" /> 
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
 <Storyboard>
 <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="OuterContainer" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
 <Storyboard>
 <!-- These two Opacity animations are required - the FadeInThemeAnimations
 on the same elements animate an internal Opacity. -->
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="1" />

 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
 Duration="0"
 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
 <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" />
 <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText" />
 <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
 <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground" />
 <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" />
 <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" /> 
 <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="PointerOverBorder" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
 <Storyboard>
 <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
 <VisualTransition To="NotDragging" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
 </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
 </VisualStateGroup>
 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
 <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
 <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
 <Storyboard>
 <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Bottom" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
 <Storyboard>
 <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Top" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
 <Storyboard>
 <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Right" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
 <Storyboard>
 <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Left" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
 <VisualTransition To="NoReorderHint" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
 </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
 </VisualStateGroup>
 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
 <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
 <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
 <Storyboard>
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
 Duration="0">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
 <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
 </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
 </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect"
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
 Duration="0">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
 <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
 </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
 </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 </VisualStateGroup>
 </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
 <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
 <Path x:Name="SelectingGlyph" Opacity="0" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,9.5,9.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
 <Border x:Name="HintGlyphBorder"
 Height="40"
 Width="40"
 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
 VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Opacity="0"
 Margin="4">
 <Path x:Name="HintGlyph" Opacity="0" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
 </Border>
 <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
 <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent">
 <Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder"
 IsHitTestVisible="False"
 Opacity="0"
 Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
 Margin="1" />
 <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual"
 IsHitTestVisible="False"
 Opacity="0"
 StrokeThickness="2"
 Stroke="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" />
 <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground"
 Margin="4"
 Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
 Opacity="0" />
 <Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
 Margin="4"> 
 <Grid>
 <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
 ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
 ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
 Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
 HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
 VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
 <!-- The 'Xg' text simulates the amount of space one line of text will occupy.
 In the DataPlaceholder state, the Content is not loaded yet so we
 approximate the size of the item using placeholder text. -->
 <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
 Opacity="0"
 Text="Xg"
 Foreground="{x:Null}"
 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
 IsHitTestVisible="False"
 AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
 <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect"
 Visibility="Collapsed"
 Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
 <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
 IsHitTestVisible="False"
 Opacity="0"
 Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
 </Grid>
 </Border>
 <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBorder"
 IsHitTestVisible="False"
 Opacity="0"
 Stroke="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
 StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"
 Margin="4" />
 <Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"
 IsHitTestVisible="False"
 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
 VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Margin="4">
 <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Opacity="0" Height="40" Width="40">
 <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
 <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
 </Grid>
 </Border>
 <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}"
 Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
 FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
 FontSize="26.667"
 IsHitTestVisible="False"
 Opacity="0"
 TextWrapping="Wrap"
 TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
 Margin="18,9,0,0"
 AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
 </Grid>
 </Border>
 </Grid>
 </Border>
 </ControlTemplate>
 </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```